# Integrate grails into my Java EE application

Tags: java, grails

I have a simple Java EE application using Servlets and JSP.

Now I want to develop new functionality using Grails within the same application not a new application. Can I add Grails to my existing application?

Answer (score 0):

It very well depends on the framework u r currently using. I'd try with adding grails' lib subdirectory to the project classpath.

Comment: well I am using plain servlet jsp  no other framework. Please suggest me if I add add some grails pages to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have more luck the other way round - create a new Grails application, put your existing servlets into `src/java`, then run `grails install-templates` and edit the template web.xml to add your `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` tags to that. But note that Grails installs a number of filters that intercept all urls, and these may adversely affect your servlets. You'll have to try it and see what breaks...